# Groovy build variable name

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have SoapUI groovy test step with loop.
In every loop I want to check if variable contains number e.g. 1.

for example:

1. start loop for 'order-management'
2. change 'order-management' to 'order_management'
3. check if variable 'order_management' contains value from variable 'ppp'
4. write: "Success!"

I tried to make this script, but it doesn't work:

```
def order_management = [1,3,5]
def customer_management = [2,6,3]
def document_management = [1,3,2]

def list = ['order-management', 'customer-management', 'document-management']
list.each {

def ppp = 1

if (("${it}".replace("-","_")).contains(ppp)) {
        log.info ("Success!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def order_management = [1,3,5]
```

is just a declaration of the local variable in the script and you can't access local variable as a property by name.

you can put all *-management data into a map:

```
def data=[
    'order-management'    : [1,3,5],
    'customer-management' : [2,6,3],
    'document-management' : [1,3,2],
]
```

and to avoid using `replace("-","_")` keep in keys the `-` sign

finally your code could look like this:

```
def data=[
    'order-management'    : [1,3,5],
    'customer-management' : [2,6,3],
    'document-management' : [1,3,2],
]
def ppp = 1

data.each{k,v->
    if ( v.contains(ppp)) {
        println ("found $ppp in $k")
    }
}
```

Comment: And how to use '.contains' if ppp variable will be different for every loop? Every loop I will call test case to send request with 'management name of that loop', transfer ppp value from response to this groovy. So it means that ppp will be different for order-management and document-management. I need to define ppp value in that loop. Thanks

Comment: Declare it and evaluate inside the loop. It was a constant in your code, so I moved it outside...

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. Now I found that I missed one character in that. So now it works, thank you.